# Nginx, как сделать балансировку?

Tags: nginx

**Есть такой upstream:**

```
upstream nodes {
    hash $request_uri;

    server node-1;
    server node-2;
}
```

**И соответственно proxy для него:**

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://nodes;
}
```

Сейчас балансировка идет на основании хеша из `$request_uri`.

**Вопросы:**

**1)** Как сделать `hash` на основании своего, http хедера. Например `MyHeader`.

**2)** Как сделать `hash` на основании части пути. Важно, чтобы это не повлияло на функциональность, я говорю о `rewrite`.

Например, для пути `/api/CREATE_HASH_FROM_ME/users`
Хеш нужно взять из `CREATE_HASH_FROM_ME`.
А из пути хеш убрать, то есть путь должен стать вида: `/api/users`:

Как такое выполнить?

Comment: Использовать директиву map

Comment: 1) https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_

Comment: То есть для извлечения заголовка нужно сделать так: `$http_MyHeader`?

Comment: Да. . . . . . .

Comment: Спасибо, ну а с этим как быть: `/api/CREATE_HASH_FROM_ME/users`